# Inconsistent query result

Tags: clojure, datomic

This is question pertaining datomic on-prem, version 1.0.6202

When I do this:

```
(d/q '[:find ?LDCustomer-influencer :in $ [?user ...] 
       :where [?LDCustomer-influencer :LDCustomer/baseUser ?LDUser-influencer]
              [?LDCustomer-influencer :LDCustomer/isInfluencer ?val]
              [(= ?val true)]]
     (d/db db/conn) #{17592186248068})
```

I get:

```
#{}
```

When I do this:

```
(d/q '[:find ?LDCustomer-influencer :in $ [?user ...]
       :where [?LDCustomer-influencer :LDCustomer/baseUser ?LDUser-influencer]
              [?LDCustomer-influencer :LDCustomer/isInfluencer true]]
     (d/db db/conn) #{17592186248068})
```

I get:

```
#{[17592186093717] [17592186246464] [17592186248205] [17592186233070]}
```

(which is the correct result)

Why isn't the = operator working here?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about datomic, and I'm no java guru but consider this

```
user=> (= true [1]) 
false
user=> (= true 1)
false


(clojure.repl/source clojure.core/=) 
; uses `clojure.lang.Util/equiv under the hood
; https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java#L24

static public boolean equiv(Object k1, Object k2){
    if(k1 == k2)       // !! this will be false
        return true;
    if(k1 != null)     // !! neither of these will succeed
        {
        if(k1 instanceof Number && k2 instanceof Number)
            return Numbers.equal((Number)k1, (Number)k2);
        else if(k1 instanceof IPersistentCollection || k2 instanceof IPersistentCollection)
            return pcequiv(k1,k2);
        return k1.equals(k2);
        }
    return false;      // !! you end up with false
}
```

which I think in the end boils down to the following java

```
(Object) Integer.valueOf(1) == (Object) Boolean.valueOf(true)
```

which is false

Answer (score 0):

You have to make constant binding as "ground".  In datomic, it is like `[(ground true) ?val]`.  However, if you leave the constant in the tuples (like in your second case) datomic will take it as "grounded" by default.